# What exactly is the Mussar movement and how does it differ from mainstream Judaism?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, mussar-ethics, heterodox

I've been hearing the term "Mussar Movement" being used a lot more often as of late and I even saw some advertisements for it on other Jewish forums. ***I'm speaking to a specific movement, not just the concept of Mussar in Judaism.***

What I gathered is it frames itself as a type of deeper spiritual movement like Kabbalah does but it also incorporates Reform-like philosophies. The history I read shows it came up in Lithuania in the 1800s which makes sense considering that was around the time Reform Judaism really came up.

I was just curious if there was a clear explanation as to what it is and how it relates to Jewish practice.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musar_movement

Comment: Not sure who would claim today that the mussar movement had Reform like philosophies...

Comment: @robev That criticism is actually made in the wikipedia source Alex made. 

""Many opposed the new educational system that Yisrael Salanter set up, and others charged that deviations from traditional methods would lead to assimilation no less surely than the path of classic German Reform Judaism.""

Comment: "deeper spiritual movement like Kabbalah does" - Do you mean to imply that Kabbalah is a movement, that it frames itself as such or neither?

Comment: I said **today**, not historically.

Comment: @WAF There actually is a "Kabbalah Movement" which has sort of detached itself from Judaism and become its own thing. I'm speaking to specific movements you can point to. The Kabbalah Center in NYC is the one I was emphasizing when I made that statement. They cater to Kabbalah infused with a "New Age" mysticism which gets a lot of criticism.

Comment: Why are you assuming that there is a mainstream?

Answer (score 8):

The musar movement is mostly associated with [Rabbi Yisra'el Salanter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Salanter) and his students. There is a lot that could be said about it, but I will write mostly about the more controversial aspects and differences in Jewish practice, rather than, for example, psychological insights.

Rabbi Yisra'el advocated taking the time to learn works of musar. Already in his [Letter of Musar](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14564&st=&pgnum=104) ([English](http://www.aishdas.org/igeresHamussar.pdf)), he says that intellectual knowledge isn't enough; he recommends visualizing "a sword between your legs and hell beneath you" ([the Talmud](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.7a.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says this about a judge; he explicitly generalized this statement to everyone). Learning musar was not just reading a book; after the intellectual understanding it had to be repeated ["with an excited soul, a ready heart, a distraught voice, burning lips."](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14564&st=&pgnum=32) But even apart from his special method, his advocating actually learning musar at set times and at set places (he required [a special place for this learning](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14564&st=&pgnum=31)), in addition to learning standard books of Torah, was a novelty. One of his students, Rabbi Simcha Zisel Ziv, opened up a [Talmud Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelm_Talmud_Torah), i.e. a yeshiva, in which musar was one of the prominently studied subjects, not only more traditional subjects such as Talmud. This was controversial and sometimes unpopular even within; in [another yeshiva](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeshivas_Knesses_Yisrael_(Slabodka)) the students actually [revolted](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7265&pgnum=88) against this type of learning and forced it to split into two.

Another novelty with regard to Jewish practice was that ethical behavior is actually a law on par with other religious obligations. In his [Letter of Musar](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14564&st=&pgnum=105) he bemoans the fact that while people are careful to eat kosher food, they are not careful in their business dealings. The Torah counts both of them as commandments, and yet people who would never violate the commandment not to eat non-kosher food aren't careful not to cheat in business.

In other cases, Rabbi Yisra'el "discovered" unnoticed laws in the Talmud. One example would be [his close reading](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14564&pgnum=114) of the law in certain cases (e.g. [Bava Metsi'a 6:1](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Bava_Metzia.6.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)), that if two parties deceived each other, the only claim they have against the other party is "a complaint." He learns from this that the right to have a complaint against someone is a legal right just like any other monetary claim. When the Torah allows you to have a complaint, you can have a complaint. Conversely, if you forgive the other party, you are no longer allowed to have a complaint against him, just like you wouldn't be allowed to demand his money if you had forgiven a monetary claim. (And, he continues, you can use this trick to stop fighting with a person: you can forgive him, which will legally forbid you to retain any anger against him.)

For more information about the movement, you might want to read Rabbi Dov Katz's five-volume [Tenu'at Hamusar](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A2%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8_(%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8)) (unfortunately not online) and [Pulmus Hamusar](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/7265) (about the controversy surrounding the movement). The primary source for Rabbi Yisra'el of Salant are his letters, nearly all published posthumously in Rabbi Yitschak Blazer's [Or Yisra'el](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/14564).

Comment: I was not aware that is pulmus hamusar

Comment: Rabbi Katz came out with a multi-volume history of the Mussar Movement, with a focus on some of the key people and their ideas. The last volume, omitted from more recent editions, is titled Pulmus HaMussar, meaning, The Mussar Controversy.

Comment: @MichaBerger Wasn't that what I wrote? Or did you mean to add something?

Comment: @kouty didn't get what you meant, apparently, so I intentionally just repeated in different words. See their comment just above mine.

Comment: I don’t really understand the question, but this is a great answer! +1

Answer (score 2):

Speaking as someone who works to revive ideas from the Mussar Movement... (My credentials in this regard : I teach for The Mussar Institute, whose target audience is primarily spiritually seeking non-Orthodox Jews, I founded the AishDas society, whose target audience is Orthodox synagogues, and I just came out with a Mussar text.)

At the time Rav Yisrael Salanter came to the scene, Jewish Thought was split between Chassidus and the notion that our primary goal in life is a relationship with G-d, and the Lithuanian tradition which defined the goal in terms of self-refinement. I just wrote an [answer about this to another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98986/1570).

But to address the subject from within, as opposed to focusing on context...

### Foundation Stories

There are two foundation stories about the birth of the Mussar Movement (which should not be confused with mussar as a whole).

The first is where a young Yisrael Lipkin used to follow R’ Zundel Salanter around. Rav Zundel wanted to live privately, secretly, so Rav Yisrael had to sneak around to watch the actions of this ba’al mussar. One time, he followed Rav Zundel into the woods, where Rav Zundel engaged in passionate hispa’alus (pouring out his soul “with lips aflame”). (No, this really isn’t a Breslov story…) Suddenly, Rav Zundel turned around, made eye contact, and instructed, “ישראל, לערן מוסרת, אז דו זאלסט וערען א ירא שמים — Learn mussar so that you will be one who lives in awe of [the One in] Heaven!” In Nesivos Or it writes that Rav Yisrael Salanter called the moment a “thunderbolt” that changed his life.

The second was a time on Yom Kippur when Rav Yisrael didn’t have a machzor with him. At one point he got lost, and needed to peer over the other person’s shoulder. He got shoved in response to his efforts. How dare you shterr my kavanah (harm my concentration)! At that point Rav Yisrael realized that he couldn’t keep Mussar to himself, and had to share it with the world.

Hold onto those, I’ll get back to them.

So to ask again: What is mussar?

I’m going to answer that with a set of three triads.

### First Triad

There are three ways to see the relationship between tiqun hamiddos (repairing the dimensions of one’s personality traits) and halakhah. They are far from mutually exclusive.

1- The Rambam’s Hilkhos Dei’os describes the obligations specific to personality. They are obligations among other halakhah‘s other obligations.

2- Without tiqun hamiddos, one is incapable of making the right decisions at the actual time one is faced with a choice. It is the means by which one is capable of following halakhah to an ever greater extent. Mussar is a central component to Judaism, but logically inferior to halakhah.

While the first notion is universal, for even the gemara asserts (for example) “whomever loses their temper it is as though they worshiped idols”, this one is only nearly universal. It is not consistent with some forms of Chassidus. Chassidus is inherently experiential in nature. Breslov argues that trying to over-analyze or work at it would actually get in the way of the experience.

3- The entire purpose of halakhah is to achieve sheleimus ha’adam (completeness of the person), to finish Hashem’s creation — “let us make man in our image”. The use of plural can be taken to include both Hashem and the person himself. Perfection of the “image” of G-d which by definition must be self made — as He is. Thus, all of halakhah is an exercise in tiqun hamiddos. Halakhah is logically a consequence of Mussar.

And it is fair to assert that the two to coexist symbioticly, seeing mussar is the only way to fully follow halakhah and seeing halakhah as the critical means of achieving mussar‘s goal. Two sides of one integral whole.

This notion is far from universal — it’s the sheleimus (personal wholeness) fork in the road of Jewish philosophy. Chassidus took the other route, deveiqus (cleaving to G-d). Others have argued non-personal perfection as a goal — perfection of society, or of the Jewish community. And Brisk would argue against the entire concept of defining goals; halakhah must be understood on its own terms.

### Second triad

A rebbe-chaveir of mine, R’ Dr Ephraim Becker, describes mussar (in the third sense of the previous triad) as a three part thing:
– There is the real, knowing where one stands
– There is the ideal, knowing where the Creator wants us to be
– There is the process of getting from the real to the ideal

There is an interesting contrast in book titles. When R’ Yaakov Hillel wrote a book on Jewish philosophy, he called it “Ascending Jacob’s Ladder”. When Dr Alan Morinis documented his path back to classical Judaism by studying Mussar under R’ Yechiel Perr he titled his book “Climbing Jacob’s Ladder”. (Rabbi Perr is the rosh yeshiva of Derech Ayson, Far Rockaway NY, and scion of Novhardok three different ways.) Ascending, with no mention of work, vs climbing.

To go to primary sources, note that Rav Zundel Salanter told the future Rav Yisrael Salanter “zal tzuzain a yarei Shamayim” — not to gain awareness of the significance of the One in heaven, but to become the kind of person who has such awareness. As I wrote above, Chassidus tries for deveiqus. The Mussar Movement asserted that one must try to become kind of person capable of deveiqus. There could be no other reason why deveiqus isn’t achieved. Hashem would leave no break between Him and us. The break is between us and ourselves.

It is this notion of process, of climbing — literally “shteigin” — that is of value within nearly all derakhim, all paths, all approaches to the Torah. And thus lower case “m”, not specifically the Mussar Movement. The different derakhim define the ideal by stressing different aspects of it. Which will in turn suggests different paths, thus the name “derakhim“. But using tools to become the kind of person who can follow that path, to consciously pursue that derekh’s perspective on the end-goal, makes sense according to any derekh.

### Third Triad

Note that the story with Rav Zundel portrays mussar as the route to becoming a yarei Shamayim. The one about the man who wouldn’t share his machzor for a moment focuses on his being so enraptured in Yom Kippur’s theme of teshuvah he neglects a central part of that — his relationship to the person standing next to him. It tells of the need to refocus the masses who were increasingly looking to rite, to defend our self-definition as Reform tried to tear it away. Following along the tefillah on Yom Kippur to the exclusion of more fundamental mitzvos. And that second theme is central to how R’ Yisrael is portrayed; most of the stories told about him are about being stringent in interpersonal mitzvos over common stringencies in mitzvos between man and the Omnipresent.

Mussar is also very centrally a third theme — tiqun hamiddos. (Thus completing our last triad.) Whether it’s Mesilas Yesharim’s working up the ladder of middos up to divine inspiration or Cheshbon haNefesh’s list of middos that have more interpersonal implications. And this is true even in the “Hilkhos Dei’os” sense of Mussar, never mind the approaches in the first triad that make tiqun hamiddos even more central.

We can view the goals of the Mussar Movement as creating a “holistic Jew”, one who works on his relationship with the Creator, with other people, and with himself. And compared to where the other man in shul and his ilk stood, that means a greater stress on interpersonal and intrapersonal (bein adam lenafsho, between man and his soul, as the Gra put it) mizvos than one sees in other paths to serving the A-lmighty. And if that’s true of 19th cent Lithuania, it’s even more true of today’s society, with its providing grist for “chumrah of the month club” jokes.

That would explain why Rav Yisrael is so associated with stories stressing the interpersonal. Had the Judaism of his day been more centered on that, the stories retold about him would be about prayer, etc… E.g. the Mussar Movement promoted tefillah behispa’alus; a minyan no less passionate (and possibly no quieter) than anything found among Karliner chassidim.

### Mussar Today

Using the real-ideal-path concept:

Rav Kook taught a philosophy. He therefore defines an ideal, but no way to become the kind of person who can live up to it. For that matter, Rav Samson Raphael Hirsch doesn’t either. Rav Hirsch is closer to the Mussar Movement in ideal — both aim at a refined Jew. Different focuses on refinement, but it’s no coincidence both Slabodka and Hirsch’s Torah im Derekh Eretz produced well groomed, secularly informed, doers. But Rav Hirsch didn’t discuss the means to get there.

Mussar in the loose sense is encapsulated in the notion of finding and following a path from the real me to the ideal me. It requires belief that tiqun hamiddos is a prerequisite for being able to follow halakhah. (In shorthand: Embracing the first triad, real-ideal-path, and at least the second but also possibly all three positions about the role of mussar in a halachic life.)

This kind of Mussar can therefore be applied within most derakhim. One can live by Rav Hirsch’s definition of the ideal or the Tanya’s and still seek to transform oneself into the kind of person who better lives that ideal.

And it is in that sense that AishDas strives to promote mussar.

Mussar in the sense of the Mussar Movement requires embracing all three triads in full: adopting the notion that sheleimus ha’adam is the entire tachlis of the Torah, perfecting our tzelem E-lokim. And being whole can only be possible with full attention to all three relationships. Thus Rav Yisrael was lead to balancing all three of Shim’on haTzadiq’s pillars (Avos 1:2) equally: Torah’s perfection of the self, Avodas Hashem, and Gemillus Chassadim toward others.

Notice what I’m excluding. I don’t see the darkness and harshness of the early Mussar Movement, with a focus on the evils of the yeitzer hara, keeping in mind the day of one’s death, the dark candle-lit room, etc… as defining for the Mussar Movement. Rather, mussar inherently is very subject to knowing where you are. And therefore, the same era that created the stereotype fire-n-brimstone preacher called for a very “dark” mussar. It’s as unfair to judge it from where we stand as it is to judge the role of tokhachah in contemporary Sepharadic maggidim.

And thus, the Mussar Movement had to “repackage” itself repeatedly as people changed. Slabodka’s Gadlus haAdam is no less part of the Mussar Movement even if it dovetails well with contemporary Human Potential talk. (The Alter’s Yahrzeit is just four days away, on the 29th of Shevat.) And Rav Shelomo Wolbe (who is somewhat less of the movement, since it was really a casualty of Hitler) wrote in the 1970s about the need to focus on “planting and building” (to quote the title of his seifer on parenting) rather than pruning. Carrots, not sticks, are what work for today’s Jew.

What killed Mussar? Mussar never survived the end of East European Jewry’s golden era. But why not, whereas Chassidus is rebuilding itself?

Two yeshiva students noticed that of all the Slabodka graduates who built post-War yeshivos, only R’ Dovid Leibowitz (founding Rosh Yeshiva of Yeshivas Chofetz Chaim) strived to build a mussar yeshiva. Not R’ Aharon Kotler, R’ Yaakov Kamenecki, Rav Hutner, Rav Kahaneman, etc, etc, etc… They actually went around the US asking these rashei yeshiva why. Rav Hutner’s answer is telling. He felt that the American student couldn’t handle the long work that real change requires. Rav Hutner therefore chose the more modest goal (in his opinion) of inspiring them with the Maharal’s thought.

It is easy to be inspired by ideals. The trick is staring at the details, the step-by-step work, and still following through. And so today’s generation of Israeli Orthodox “seekers” find a home in some “chulent” Rav Kook’s and the Tanya’s philosophy and Breslover experiences and Carlebach minyanim. They do not search for a program, a plan for getting from here to there. In the US, Carlebachian Neo-Chassidus is popular because it provides inspiring experiences without that demand of the day-to-day attention to detail and following a spiritual discipline that defies America’s love of the “quick fix”. Rav Hutner, in the founding years of the American Orthodox community of today, thought all we can do is inspire people toward the ideal and hope for the best without conscious work or a plan to get there.

Given the increasing lack of a holistic, three pillar, approach to Yahadus, demonstrating a real need for mussar, and the greater strength of the community and its educational system today providing opportunity, I believe we have a sizable population ready to work for something better. To set out and build idealists — of all the various ways we have formulated the Torah’s ideals.

### Conclusion

So, to summarize. The Mussar Movement asserted three essential points, the full acceptance of each of the above triads:

1. You need to consciously follow a process to reach qedushah (holiness).
2. That process is the purpose of the Torah. Life is about the completion of the “image” of G-d within.
3. The whole person is one who perfects his relationships with Hashem, other people, and his own soul. And thus, one can’t overlook interpersonal and intrapersonal mitzvos in the pursuit of qedushah.

The lessons of mussar have value to us today, even for those who choose to view the Torah using a different framework. But one must be willing to work for qedushah if they are to fully use their potential to obtain it.

(Taken from my blog post, "[What is Mussar?](http://www.aishdas.org/asp/what-is-mussar)")

Comment: I added section headings to make it more readable. (Indeed, in the blog post you did use headings.)

Comment: Pretty amazing coincidence: If you live east of India, the date actually matches up.

Comment: @Alex, thanks for the edit. But I took out that paragraph with the date, as it doesn't fit with the StackExchange format.

Comment: Rav Hutner books are almost incomprehensible for me. It's musar?

Comment: @kouty: Rav Hutner writes Maharal based Jewish Thought. He chose this focus on inspirational writing because he felt the American psyche isn't ready for long-term projects like Mussar. We'd more likely give up before getting anywhere.