# What philosophy of life does Torah/Judaism propose to humanity?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

What is God's will for us here on earth as individuals? Living intensely within certain limits, working to get what our soul desires, relating intensely with whom we feel attracted, having children, tasting flavors and tastes, wandering around the Earth?

Some argue that this would be a secular philosophy of life or even contrary to God, that by doing this we are almost living like animals, without having that spirituality developed, is there a greater purpose down here or is this only reserved for certain enlightened people for a specific purpose about Israel as prophets and kings? Should I pursue these issues or does it just happen naturally? The ordinary citizen in Israel at the time of the kings, as far as we can see, lived normally as people of the world, being guided by what the elite of Israel leaned towards, either towards monotheism or polytheism.

In terms of philosophy of life, how do Jews see our stay here? Live as stated above only in a decent way and finally die, with no expectation that you will receive a special mission from God? I say this because it seems that living normally seems like an empty life and that it will not leave fruit or legacy, we see world and religious personalities who have done great things and we aspire to feel that contact, doesn't it have to be like that? Living normal, day after day is what we have as a creature?

Comment: 1] You probably mean to ask "how does **Judaism** see our stay here?" Jews may have many  different views. 2] At a first shot, - living according to the laws of the Torah and - developing Torah character traits would seem to be the main aims.

Comment: I speak of our daily habits, what is the purpose of all this? From this routine that the overwhelming majority of humanity deals with. I think Ecclesiastes brings up this same issue, there is nothing new under the sun, all is vanity, God loads man with work to keep them busy, our portion is to eat the fruit of our labor in the few days we live, is there nothing to be achieved beyond that? Is everything this futility and one day die?

Comment: This calls for a survey of the range of answers, not an answer. I wrote a book about one stream's answer, but I think an outline of that survey would be more appropriate

Comment: Does my answer at https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/98986/1570 address what you are looking for?

Comment: Life is a way to end up better than when you started, so that you are more prepared for future forms of existence. That involves engaging in this world, as the events in our lives and encounters with other people are the means by which Hashem provides our curriculum.